# kql - get all values from a dictionary

Tags: arrays, dictionary, kql

Is it possible to get an array of values from a dictionary?

```
let T = datatable(prop:string, value:string)
[
    "prop01", "val_a",
    "prop02", "val_b",
    "prop03", "val_c",
];
T
| extend p = pack(prop, value)
| summarize dict=make_bag(p)
```

I need `["val_a","val_b","val_"]`

Smth like Python `myDict.values()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `mv-apply` + `make_list()` to achieve that.

you can also submit a feature request for a `bag_values()` function @ https://aka.ms/adx.ideas.

```
datatable(dict:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
        "prop01": "val_a",
        "prop02": "val_b",
        "prop03": "val_c"
    }), 
]
| mv-apply dict on (
    extend key = tostring(bag_keys(dict)[0])
    | summarize values = make_list(dict[key])
)
| project values
```

| values |
| --- |
| [ "val_a", "val_b", "val_c" ] |